# Python&Pandas How to get all the rows that belongs to each one of the 4 quartiles of the method "describe"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, analytics

Good night!

I'm new in coding, my english isn't so good and it's my second post here, so please be patient with me =]

I have a huuuge csv file (more than 500k rows) with a huge amount of interest rates in the last column.

[image: A piece of the csv]

I need to:

**a)** Use the method describe in the column vr_tx_jrs to get minimum value, maximum value and the 4 quartiles of the interest rates of the whole csv, after cleaning; **I already did it**

**b)** Create 4 dataframes, one for each one of the quartiles, to store all interest rates (vr_tx_jrs) that belong to each one of the 4 quartiles and than, use the method describe on each dataframe, because I need the median of each one of the 4 quartiles; **I'm stucked here and I have no idea how to procceed, I need your help here guys, please =D **

**c)** Calculate the frequency of each one of those 4 quartiles. Since I'm stucked on letter b I didn't get here yet. But I imagine that I need to get the len of rows of each one of those 4 data frames and divide by the len of the whole csv after cleaning, so I would get the frequency of each quartile;

I started the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

'''Importing and cleaning data'''
df_quart = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\base_ob.csv", encoding='Latin-1', sep=";")
df_quart.head()
df_quart['vr_tx_jrs'] = df_quart['vr_tx_jrs'].str.replace(',','.').astype(np.float64)
df_quart['nr_cic'] = df_quart['nr_cic'].astype(np.int64)
df_quart.dtypes
df_quart.describe()
df_quart.groupby('nr_cic').mean().reset_index() '''cleaning doubles and exchange to the mean between them

'''Here is the output to letter "a". Creating a new dataframe to store minimum and max interest rates and the 4 quartiles of the whole CSV'''

df_final = df_quart.describe()
df_final.to_excel(r"C:\Users\describe_base_ob.xlsx")
```

**Now I'm stucked in letter "B", where I need your help, guys. I searched a lot online but I have no idea how to get all the rows that belongs to each one of the 4 quartiles described in the method "describe", and store in 4 new dataframes, one for each quartile.**

Could you help me please?

Thanks and have a great day you all!! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
# Quartile value
qtile_value = 0.95

# Make new dataframe of original, being a subset as it filters for all values lower than # quartile value

quart_1 = df[df['vr_tx_jrs']<=np.quantile(df['vr_tx_jrs'], qtile_value )]
```

Just repeat quart_1 for your other 3 quantiles.

Comment: Hi buddy. Thans for your help! I tried but I got this error: ||| ValueError: Quantiles must be in the range [0, 1] ||||||||     

  3841     q = np.asanyarray(q)
   3842     if not _quantile_is_valid(q):
-> 3843         raise ValueError("Quantiles must be in the range [0, 1]")
   3844     return _quantile_unchecked(
   3845         a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)

Comment: Hi, did you use a value qtile_value between 0 and 1? Otherwise you indeed get an error

Comment: Btw, do you know how to attribute the value of 1st quartile (after use the method describe), for instance, to this variable that you created "qtile_value"? I'm asking this because the data is dynamic, I'll need to calculate each month, sou each month I'll get new values for the interest rate.

Comment: Hi, buddy! I hadn't done with value between 0 and 1. Now I did it and it's OK, Thank you so much!!! Btw, do you know how to attribute the value of 1st quartile (after use the method describe), for instance, to this variable that you created "qtile_value"? I'm asking this because the data is dynamic, I'll need to calculate each month, sou each month I'll get new values for the interest rate.

Comment: Np.quantile gives you the value of the interest rate at your specified vakue qtile_value. Is this what you mean? I dont fully understand your question I think

Comment: Thanks again, buddy! That works! Just needed to use df['vr_tx_jrs'].median() or df['vr_tx_jrs'].quantile(0.5) to get the median of the df that you teach me to create =D Have a great day!